# Not able to add new line in react-input-emoji

Tags: reactjs, emoji

I am trying to add functionality, in which shift+enter can be used for a new line. But when I am adding it, the cursor goes to the starting position and also no newline added

```
<InputEmoji
                    value={text}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    // onEnter={handleOnEnter}
                    placeholder="Type a message..."
                    onKeyDown={(e) => {
                        if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
                            var t = text + "<br/>";
                            handleChange(t);
                            //e.preventDefault();
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                //e.target.innerHtml += "<br/>"
                                const el = e.target;
                                const selection = window.getSelection();
                                const range = document.createRange();
                                selection.removeAllRanges();
                                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                                range.collapse(false);
                                selection.addRange(range);
                                el.focus();
                            }, 100);
                        }
                        else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                            //console.log(text)
                            //e.preventDefault();
                            handleOnEnter(text)
                        }
                    }}
                />
```

Can u please suggest me a better approach for newline

Answer (score -1):

Try props

```
shouldReturn={true}
```

[Try This](https://github.com/cesarwbr/react-input-emoji)